# Query entities with count of related entities computed remotely

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using ef core 2.2.6, I am trying to generate a projection that contains a parent model (without related entities loaded) and a count of one of the related entities.

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

The `Children` collection is very large and I only need the count, therfore fetching it remotely would be advantageous. I have no problem calculating the count in a projection using `Count()` or `Sum()`, I am however unable to force it to calculate the result remotely.

```
var id = 42;
var query =
    from parent in context.Parents
    join child in context.Children on parent.Id equals child.ParentId into grp
    where parent.Id == id
    select new
    {
        parent,
        count = grp.Count()
    };
```

How can I adjust this to force the count to be computed on the sql server?

Comment: Since you have a parent id, can't you just:
`context.Parents.Where(q => q.Id = id).Select(q => new { Parent = q, ChildrenCount = q.Children.Count() })` ?

Comment: The query is correctly generated and produces the count at the sql server if `Parent = q` is primitive such as `Parent = q.Id`. However when it is not, the count is produced locally. This must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the query output but it should look like this.

```
from child in context.Children group child by child.ParentId into grp
     join parent in context.Parents on grp.Key equals parent.Id
     where parent.Id==id
     select new
     {
          parent,
          count = grp.Count()
     };
```

Comment: Several warnings about GroupBy, Join and Count could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. Can you think of any condition that could continue to provoke this?

Answer (score 0):

In simplest way, you can make a DTO class as follows:

```
public class ParentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ............ // Other properties

    public int ChildrenCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then your query should be as follows:

```
 var parentWithChildCount = context.Parents.Where(p => p.Id = id).Select(p => new ParentDto
                           { 
                              Id = p.Id,

                              .................. // Map other properties

                              ChildrenCount = p.Children.Count()
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: As per my comment to @koryakinp, this (or an anonymous type) does work as long as the fields are primitive, but I need the parent tracked so I can change it after I retrieve it.